# How can I make the return type a function of the argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to figure out the Typescript for a function that takes a dictionary of key value pairs where the value is a Promise. And returns a dictionary of key value pairs where the value is the resolved Promise. I think the below code works for this. And the IArg and IResult interface don't throw any errors.

```
    interface IArg{ [key: string]: Promise<any> }
    interface IResult{ [key: string]: any extends Promise ? never : any}

    public async promiseProps(obj: IArg): Promise<IResult>{
        return Promise.all(Object.values(obj)).then(
            (values) => {
                const keys: string[] = Object.keys(obj);
                const length = keys.length;
                const d: IResult = {};
                for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
                    d[keys[i]] = values[i];
                }
                return d
            }
        )
    }
```

However what I can't figure out is how to indicate that for a specific key, the return type for that key is the type of the resolved promise.

For example if my arg is (which meets the type defined by IArg):

```
{
    foo: Promise<string>,
    bar: Promise<int>,
}
```

I want my return type to ensure that the return value meets:

```
{
    foo: string,
    bar: int,
}
```

My current return value only guarantees that the values are not Promises. Thanks!

Comment: Generics, with a mapped type that uses the built-in `Awaited` utility: https://tsplay.dev/mq9dJm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to vr. for the super helpful comment, posting an answer here to unpack a little bit.

```
async function promiseProps<T extends Record<any, Promise<any>>>(
    obj: T
): Promise<{
    [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>;
}>;
async function promiseProps(obj: object) {
    return Promise.all(Object.values(obj)).then((values) => Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(obj).map((key, i) => [key, values[i]])));
}
```

Some concepts I was missing:
generics- a way to introduce type-safety into components that accept arguments and return values whose type will be indeterminate until they are consumed later in your code.
mapped types- build on the syntax for index signatures, which are used to declare the types of properties which have not been declared ahead of time